# Getting dyngroup and memberof overlays to play nice

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have both the dynlist/dyngroup and memberof overlays working correctly in openldap but what i cannot get working is getting the memberof to display groups that a user is added to through the dyngroup overlay.

Does anyone know of a way to get that working?

```
dn: uid=useraccount,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
memberOf: cn=employees,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
memberOf: cn=devops,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
departmentNumber: IT

cn=IT,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: IT
objectClass: groupOfURLs
objectClass: top
memberURL: ldap:///ou=users,dc=domain,dc=com??one?(departmentNumber=IT)
member: uid=useraccount,ou=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user isn't 'added to [groups] by the dyngroup overlay'. The overlay makes it *appear* that that's the case, but the actual memberships are computed at runtime, not represented statically in the DIT, which is what the memberOf overlay is designed to help you with.